# svg images disappears on page reload in django

Tags: python, html, django, svg

I have a view that gets an `.svg` image for an "`entry_nr`" (don't worry about this) which looks a bit like this:

```
def svg_image(request, entry_nr):
    svg_string = utils.DrawSVG.get_svg(entry_nr)
    return HttpResponse(svg_string)
```

The url for this is then:

```
url(r'^images/(?P<entry_nr>[0-9]+)/$', views.svg_image, name='svg_image')
```

When I load the url in my browser for a given `entry_nr`,  I can see the `.svg` - it works. But for some reason, when I refresh the page, the image disappears and I have to restart the server to see it again.

Why might this be?

Ultimately the `.svg`'s are loaded into a template using `<img src="/location/images/{{memb.EntryNr}}>"` (where `memb.EntryNr` is the `entry_nr`) and right now the images do not load at all. I'm assuming it's for the same reason.

**EDIT:** The `get_svg` function uses the `render` function of a 3rd party python library to render the `.svg`, then returns the string. The `render` function needs a file to save to:

```
def get_svg(renderable_object):
    t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".svg")
    renderable_object.render(t.name)
    t.file.seek(0)
    svg_string = t.read()
    t.close()
    return svg_string
```

Also, when I refresh an `entry_nr` page (as explained above) I get this message in the terminal many times over: `QObject::startTimer: QTimer can only be used with threads started with QThread`

Comment: could you add a sippet of the get_svg method. I think the problem is there.

Comment: @cchristelis thanks, please see edit

Comment: Make sure that you are actually doing a lookup on entry number every time before calling get_svg. I.e. a new lookup every time.